# Tuning gunicorn (with Django): Optimize for more concurrent connections and faster connections

Tags: django, performance, webserver, lighttpd, gunicorn

I use Django 1.5.3 with gunicorn 18.0 and lighttpd. I serve my static and dynamic content like that using lighttpd:

```
$HTTP["host"] == "www.mydomain.com" {
    $HTTP["url"] !~ "^/media/|^/static/|^/apple-touch-icon(.*)$|^/favicon(.*)$|^/robots\.txt$" {
            proxy.balance = "hash"
            proxy.server = ( "" => ("myserver" =>
                       ( "host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 8013 )
            ))
    }

    $HTTP["url"] =~ "^/media|^/static|^/apple-touch-icon(.*)$|^/favicon(.*)$|^/robots\.txt$" {
            alias.url = (
                    "/media/admin/" => "/var/www/virtualenvs/mydomain/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/",
                    "/media" => "/var/www/mydomain/mydomain/media",
                    "/static" => "/var/www/mydomain/mydomain/static"
            )
    }

    url.rewrite-once = (
            "^/apple-touch-icon(.*)$" => "/media/img/apple-touch-icon$1",
            "^/favicon(.*)$" => "/media/img/favicon$1",
            "^/robots\.txt$" => "/media/robots.txt"
    )
}
```

I already tried to run gunicorn (via supervisord) in many different ways, but I cant get it better optimized than it can handle about 1100 concurrent connections. In my project I need about 10000-15000 connections

```
command = /var/www/virtualenvs/myproject/bin/python /var/www/myproject/manage.py run_gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:8013 -w 9 -k gevent --preload --settings=myproject.settings
command = /var/www/virtualenvs/myproject/bin/python /var/www/myproject/manage.py run_gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:8013 -w 10 -k eventlet --worker_connections=1000 --settings=myproject.settings --max-requests=10000
command = /var/www/virtualenvs/myproject/bin/python /var/www/myproject/manage.py run_gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:8013 -w 20 -k gevent --settings=myproject.settings --max-requests=1000
command = /var/www/virtualenvs/myproject/bin/python /var/www/myproject/manage.py run_gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:8013 -w 40 --settings=myproject.settings
```

On the same server there live about 10 other projects, but CPU and RAM is fine, so this shouldnt be a problem, right?

I ran a load test and these are the results:
[image: load test]

At about 1100 connections my lighttpd errorlog says something like that, thats where the load test shows the drop of connections:

```
2013-10-31 14:06:51: (mod_proxy.c.853) write failed: Connection timed out 110
2013-10-31 14:06:51: (mod_proxy.c.939) proxy-server disabled: 127.0.0.1 8013 83
2013-10-31 14:06:51: (mod_proxy.c.1316) no proxy-handler found for: /

... after about one minute
2013-10-31 14:07:02: (mod_proxy.c.1361) proxy - re-enabled: 127.0.0.1 8013
```

These things also appear ever now and then:

```
2013-10-31 14:06:55: (network_linux_sendfile.c.94) writev failed: Connection timed out 600
2013-10-31 14:06:55: (mod_proxy.c.853) write failed: Connection timed out 110
...
2013-10-31 14:06:57: (mod_proxy.c.828) establishing connection failed: Connection timed out
2013-10-31 14:06:57: (mod_proxy.c.939) proxy-server disabled: 127.0.0.1 8013 45
```

So how can I tune gunicorn/lighttpd to serve more connections faster? What can I optimize? Do you know any other/better setup?

Thanks alot in advance for your help!

**Update: Some more server info**

root@django ~ # top

```
top - 15:28:38 up 100 days,  9:56,  1 user,  load average: 0.11, 0.37, 0.76
Tasks: 352 total,   1 running, 351 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 33.0%us,  1.6%sy,  0.0%ni, 64.2%id,  0.4%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.7%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  32926156k total, 17815984k used, 15110172k free,   342096k buffers
Swap: 23067560k total,        0k used, 23067560k free,  4868036k cached
```

root@django ~ # iostat

```
Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64 (django.myserver.com)   10/31/2013      _x86_64_        (4 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
      33.00    0.00    2.36    0.40    0.00   64.24

Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
sda             137.76       980.27      2109.21  119567783  257268738
sdb              24.23       983.53      2112.25  119965731  257639874
sdc              24.25       985.79      2110.14  120241256  257382998
md0               0.00         0.00         0.00        400          0
md1               0.00         0.00         0.00        284          6
md2            1051.93        38.93      4203.96    4748629  512773952
```

root@django ~ # netstat -an |grep :80 |wc -l

```
7129
```

Kernel Settings:

```
echo "10152 65535" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
sysctl -w fs.file-max=128000
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=300
sysctl -w net.core.somaxconn=250000
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog=2500
sysctl -w net.core.netdev_max_backlog=2500
ulimit -n 10240
```

Comment: Before you go significant effort into optimizing, you may need to consider other options, as reaching 10000+ concurrent connections may not be possible. That being said, start trying to isolate the bottle necks. The two obvious components are gunicorn and lighttpd. I'd start by cutting out lighttpd proxying and see how many connections gunicorn can do since its likely the bottleneck. If it is, you'll have to look at what takes a long time in it, I know nothing about gunicorn, but you'll need to speed up request processing or increase total concurrent connections possible.

Comment: Utilize something like: http://newrelic.com/ (application performance monitor) to identify over time which areas of your app should get your optimization. Most likely it's the database that's slowing things now for a web app.

Comment: Thanks @stormlifter, thats actually what I did a few months ago and yes, it was the datebase! ;)

Comment: See if you can configure several processes for the backend. Each will have to have a separate port configured. And decrease the cooldown period to something like a second or two. If that doesn't help, you might have to upgrade the hardware itself; placing the database onto an SSD (assuming it doesn't fit into RAM) could be a start.